# itext2.1.7 and itext5.0.5 not working in same java web application

Tags: java, itext

I have 2 itext version jar files for generating the different reports in my web application.
jar file versions is itext 2.1.7 and itext 5.0.5.
itext2.1.7 for generating the PDF jasper reports. itext 5.0.5 is used for converting html file into pdf.

How can we do this?Please suggest as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

You should change the code you have from the old version to new version. If this is not an option for you, find ways to package the old library on a different package.